# Any information on where I can find SDK information facebook

Tags: php, facebook

Hey does anybody know where I can find information php about facebook users who use facebook to register to another site. I want to find out how I can post on the users wall after they have confirmed they want to register to my website using facebook. Here is some code:

```
     <iframe class="facebook-login" src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/registration.php?
     client_id=USERS_ID&
     redirect_uri=http://domain.com/sign_up.php&
     fields=<?php echo urlencode($fields);?>"
```

I want to be able to post on the users wall who register to my website using facebook. Does anybody have any information regarding this topic?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook has a detailed example to show how to post a link using PHP and FB API here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/postwithgraphapi/

P/s: Remember to get user permission to write on his wall first.